# Core 2 Tag Helpers not showing in the editor, even after multiple VS reinstalls.

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core-2.0

For anyone that doesn't already know what a tag helper is. This is what a tag helper is.

```
<input asp-for="Forename" class="form-control" />
```

Previously, when I begun typing "asp-for" intelisense would suggest all the properties of the model. As you can imagine, this was extremely useful. 
However, not only has intelisense stopped working, but Visual Studio seems to have completely forgotten that tag helpers exist.

Previously, these tag helpers were shown in green, and they would be flagged up as errors if the property you'd used, for example, did not exist.

Now, I have no such luck. Visual studio now just renders them the same it would any other HTML element.

**How they look now:**

[image]

**How they should look:** (taken on another computer)

[image]

**Importantly** these tag helpers -do- work. The ones that I wrote before the problem work fine, and if I manually and very carefully copy paste the names of the model properties over, they work fine too. This is just an extremely inefficient way of doing it, and makes things hard to debug when something goes wrong.

**Additional Information**

- This is not a code problem. This is a project, and everyone is using the same project. It works perfectly for them
- I have reinstalled the ASP.NET stuff in the VS installer, I have "repaired" my install of Visual Studio, then I reinstalled Visual Studio by uninstalling it and reinstalling. I have **no** plugins running.
- Another bizarre factor here is that this problem started out intermittent, being fixed when I closed and re-opened the project, then being fixed when I restarted the computer, and then eventually not working at all, ever.

Comment: Go to the folder where you .sln file is. From View->Hidden Items, check it so that hidden items are visible. You will see a ".vs" folder. Delete this and restart visual studio.This should fix intelisense issues.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have fixed it.

Comment: Make sure you have the Razor Language Services extension installed. Should be there by default, if you installed Visual Studio with ASP.NET Core support, but maybe it got removed or disabled somehow.

Comment: Definitely have that installed too. Tried disabling and re-enabling it, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this in the future, I never did solve the issue. However I did find the source of the problem.

It was something to do with the project file, although I have no idea what was actually wrong with it.

I fixed the issue by transfering all the files into a new project (with a non-broken project file) and then re-installing all the nuget packages. I wish I could have found a better way of doing this, but I couldn't. Hope this helps if you're ever in this situation.